# Kubernetes Ingress Controller & LoadBalancer on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ingress

I want to create a single node K8S cluster on AWS and run a simple demo app, exposed to the outside world on port 80. How do I do this?

Conceptually I understand that I need a pod which is defined by a deployment and exposed by an AWS load balancer. I don't understand how k8s has permissions to create an ELB on my behalf?

The waiter container image is [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/adamgardnerdt/waiter).

Here's where I'm at. All instructions are taken from [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy):

1) Create the cluster with Ansible (geerlingguy.docker and geerlingguy.kubernetes roles). This role uses `kubeadm`.

2) Run the mandatory command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

3) Run the Layer 4 commands (I arbitrarily picked L4):

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/aws/service-l4.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/aws/patch-configmap-l4.yaml
```

4) Verify the installation:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx --watch

NAMESPACE       NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-...   1/1     Running   0
```

5) Create the service:

```
kubectl apply -f service.yaml

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: firstappservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: firstapp
```

6) Create the deployment:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: firstapp
  labels:
    app: firstapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: firstapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: firstapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: waiter
        image: adamgardnerdt/waiter:v1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, yet fundamental. Granted I am a complete Kubernetes noob.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this would be to deploy the [aws-alb-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller).

> The AWS ALB Ingress Controller satisfies Kubernetes ingress resources by provisioning Application Load Balancers.

k8s get permissions to create ELB resources on your behalf through IAM like everything in AWS.

> AWS API Access
>
> To perform operations, the controller must have required IAM role capabilities for accessing and provisioning ALB resources. There are many ways to achieve this, such as loading AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as environment variables or using kube2iam.
>
> A sample IAM policy, with the minimum permissions to run the controller, can be found in [alb-iam-policy.json](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/examples/iam-policy.json).

[aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/controller/config/](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/controller/config/)

Comment: Thanks Henrik. For my background knowledge, is it possible to create a cluster on AWS but without using their load balancers? I was thinking something like the nginx ingress controller?